# How to get specific object values from java <List> and convert to String Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need your assistant and help in getting the values of an object in a Java  and then to convert the output to String Array so I can pass it to a procedure. Here is my Java class:

```
public class PendingRequests  {

    private String requestDate; //Getter & Setter
    private String requestNo; //Getter & Setter
    private String employeeName; //Getter & Setter

}
```

And in the bean I am defining a List called "selectedRequests":

```
private List<PendingRequests> selectedRequests;
```

The selectedRequests is having values and I need to get the values of the requestNo from it and then convert it to String Array. With my attempts, I was only able to print them in the console by using the below code:

```
for(Object obj : selectedRequests){
    System.out.println("Obj = "+((PendingRequests)obj).getRequestNo());
```

But is it the correct way and what should I do next?

Comment: As a sidenote, you could just say `for(PendingRequests obj : selectedRequests)` if your `ArrayList` is declared with the Generic `PendingRequests`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String[] requestNos = new String[selectedRequests.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < selectedRequests.size(); i++) {
    requestNos[i] = selectedRequests.get(i).getRequestNo();
}
```

And here is the Java 8 version of the same thing:

```
String[] requestNos = selectedRequests
                          .stream()
                          .map(r -> r.getRequestNo())
                          .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: So that I have an index into the array, yes.

Comment: Kind of detail for the OP but what if the list is a ``LinkedList``? Better: ``int i = 0; for(r : selectedRequests) { requestNos[i++] = r.getRequestNo(); } )``

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] stringArray = new String[selectedRequests.size()];
int i =0;
for(PendingRequests request: selectedRequests){
   stringArray[i] = request.getRequestNo();
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8:

```
selectedRequests.stream()
                .map(PendingRequests::getRequestNo)
                .forEach(System.out::println)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
String[] requestNos= new String[selectedRequests.size()];
for ( int i = 0; i < selectedRequests.size() ; i++ ) {
    PendingRequests pendingRequest = selectedRequests.get(i);
    requestNos[i] = pendingRequest.getRequestNo();
}
```

forgive me it throws any errors, I just wrote it on the fly. And don't forget to add null checks as this code will throw NullPointerException if something is null.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 single line

```
String[] requestNos = selectedRequests.stream()
                      .map(
                          pr -> pr.getRequestNo()
                      )
                      .collect(Collectors.toList())
                      .toArray(new String[]{});
```